# WebGL FrameBuffer gets chopped to size of canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, framebuffer

I have recently tried to learn WebGL so im trying to make 2d game with tiled map,
most of code that renders sprites are pasted from a guide that I used to learn some basics.

Problem:
It only renders part of map that fits into canvas size, even if I apply some transformations to move map, here is my code https://github.com/LewisSaber/RPG_REBORN

I tried playing with gl.viewport function but I only got some parts of screen cut, thanks in advance

Comment: Have not looked at your code, and just a guess on my part. Binding the frame buffer `gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, myFrameBuf);` before you set the viewport `gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);`  might fix the problem.

Comment: Didnt help, but solution I found just now is to make map fit a huge amount of blocks and then use zoom to scale it back to normal size